# How to use restfull webservices with jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services, rest

Is there any good tutorial and example for restful web services using jquery & xml?
 I am pretty new to restful web services

Comment: whats your backend?? how are your webservices written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "**Enterprise Mashups with RESTful Web Services and jQuery** "? That has code details along with an explanation of how it works.

[Part 1](http://solutionsfit.com/blog/2010/04/21/enterprise-mashups-with-restful-web-services-and-jquery-part-1/)

[Part 2](http://solutionsfit.com/blog/2010/04/26/enterprise-mashups-with-restful-web-services-and-jquery-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the backend technology you're using, but a general solution with jQuery would be using `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax( {
  type:'post', //Could be 'get' depending on your needs
  url:'http://yoursite.com/yourwebservice',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success:function(data) {
     //Here you have 'data' as xml.
     //You can process 'data' here
  }
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: what the web service.. is there any demos I could refer? I am pretty new to restful web services - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

one more example

this will make an ajax call on page load for .net webservices

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RSSReader.asmx/GetRSSReader",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        //the result will be in msg
    }
  });
});
```